# Reverse the two last data from the database

Tags: sql, reverse

I want to reverse the data that are showed with the query below. `datetime_logged ASC` get the two first data from the table while `datetime_logged DESC` get the two last data. As it is right now, it prints get two last data but I want to reverse these.

**Example:** `data_temperature` with the data `9.8` comes ahead of the data `10.3`. I want to reverse this so `10.3` are ahead of `9.8`.

```
SELECT data_temperature, data_address_seo, datetime_logged
FROM weather
WHERE data_address_seo = 'street-28-postal-code-city-country'
ORDER BY datetime_logged DESC
LIMIT 2
```

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT data_temperature, data_address_seo, datetime_logged
      FROM weather
      WHERE data_address_seo = 'street-28-postal-code-city-country'
      ORDER BY datetime_logged DESC
      LIMIT 2
     ) t
ORDER BY datetime_logged;
```